# What is Microsoft Word wildcard equivalent to OR operator |

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, regex, wildcards

The OR operator in regular expressions is the pipe |.

Is there an equivalent in Microsoft Word 2016 for Mac wildcards?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: Trying to match all these words: year|juvenile|young|offspring|immature|adult

Comment: All of them or any one of them?

Comment: All of them please